# Div above a clickable link

Tags: jquery, css, html, hyperlink

I want to make a div above an another div which contains a link.
The problem is that the first div prevents to access on the link.
It's possible to make it present but accessible ?

(I don't want to make a border around a div, or something like that, i really want to make div above an other div)

**[DEMO IN FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wVLa8/)**

**HTML :**

```
<div class="top">
<a href="#">LINK</a>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.top { 
height:100px;
width:200px;
position:fixed;
top:10px;
background:yellow; }

.bottom { 
height:50px;
position:fixed;
top:10px;
width:100px;
border:3px solid red; }
```

Comment: you mean present but INaccessible?

Comment: Why have you done position fixed?

Comment: So why do you place an element on top of the element you want the user to click ?

Comment: There are several valid reasons to do so, which is why pointer-events exist. I'm not going to question his reasoning.

Comment: Name one valid reason to do so, that can't be done in some other way.

Comment: A div containing a background image that you want to be layered over something. The transparency of the background image that is layered over top of the "something" is preventing the click event from happening. Pointer-events will prevent the transparency from hiding the element from the click event. Also...almost everything can be done multiple ways.

Comment: That's a bad example, why would you put a partially transparent image on top of something else, and if you did, why not attach a click event to the partially transparent element instead, works everywhere and is just as simple. In 99.99% of the cases where you actually need to use pointer-events, you've failed in either design or behaviour, or in designing the proper behaviour.

Comment: Ok...Well, I don't come on SO to try to prove anyone wrong or start arguments just for the sake of it. If you want it that bad, its all yours buddy. :)

Comment: I don't want it at all, just pointing out that pointer-events aren't the holy grail, on the contrary, as it stands, it's a solution that doesn't work in all browsers, and clicking an anchor is usually something critically important that you'd like to have working in all browsers, not something like box shadows that is just for apperance.

Comment: Show me where I claimed or even remotely hinted that pointer-events were the holy grail lawl. Don't dwell man. I came here to help somebody that had a question. If my answer wasn't satisfactory to you, I apologize, but I promise it isn't the end of the world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `pointer-events:none;` in the CSS of .bottom

Try this:

```
.bottom { 
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    width:100px;
    border:3px solid red;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/aYV4J/

Hope it helps!

Edit: Added a fiddle

Comment: +1 for using pointer-events:none Note: only IE 11+ support pointer-events

Comment: Well, pointer-events is not the best solution as it's not cross-browser… Please see compatibility table : http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: Good piece of info Akaryatrh. I will definitely keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: Thks so much ! Just, the problem is if I want to apply a jquery animate on the "bottom" div, it doesn't work.
http://jsfiddle.net/aYV4J/2/

Comment: That would be correct. If you are trying to animate, this is not the solution for you. By adding pointer-events:none, you are making it so that the event listener for .bottom no longer trigger on pointer events.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by this way

```
.top a{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

and in `.bottom` div mention

```
.bottom { 
    z-index:1;
}
```

**[updated jsFiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/wVLa8/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

use `z-index`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wVLa8/5/)

```
.top {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    background:yellow;
    z-index:99999;
}
.bottom {
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    width:100px;
    border:3px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index` to place one over the other:

```
.top {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    z-index:1;
    background:yellow;
}
.bottom {
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    width:100px;
    border:3px solid red;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Comment: maintained equilibrium!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add with your current CSS:

```
.bottom{
    ....

    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Otherwise, you can add/increase a z-Index value for the .top class only if you don't have any z-Index limitation in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get why you guys are using `position:fixed` here. If you don't want any borders and want it to be simple then use :

```
.top { 
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    background:yellow; 
    position:relative;
}

.bottom { 
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    width:100px;
    border:3px solid red; 
    z-index:-1;
  }
```

Link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wVLa8/24/

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wVLa8/27/) .
Maybe holding the right ear with left hand but the only solution (without browser support problem) to create invisible mirror objects front of the object which makes behind objects inaccessible and let them transfer events to original objects...

```
$(function () {

    $.each($('.back').children(), function () {

        var $behindObject = $(this),
            $behindObjectOffset = $behindObject.position();

        $('<div class="invisible-mirrors">')
            .css({
                width: $behindObject.width(),
                height: $behindObject.height(),
                top: $behindObjectOffset.top,
                left: $behindObjectOffset.left
            })
            .on('click', function () {
                $behindObject.trigger("click");
            })
            .appendTo('.fore')
    });


    //test of click event

    $('.back a').on('click', function () {
        $(this).text($(this).text() + ' got the event : click')
    })


})
```

Answer (score 0):

Holy crap none of this is necessary.  Do not use Z-INDEX and do not use POINTER-EVENTS.

### [Please look at this Fiddle first](http://jsfiddle.net/tDfU9/)

Just re-arrange your HTML and name your CSS selectors correctly:

### HTML:

```
<div class="bottom">
    <div class="top"> <a href="#">LINK</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Elements considered "UNDER" or "BEFORE" other elements appear first in HTML.

### CSS:

```
.bottom {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    background:yellow;
}
.top {
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    border:3px solid red;
}
```

You also don't need them both `position: fixed;`.  Only the container.  This also means they shouldn't be one, then the other.  If you really need them like that, you can keep them both fixed as before and change the HTML but I would advise against that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it puts the Divs on top of each other:

```
.top { 
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    top:10px;
    background:yellow;
    display:block;}

.bottom { 
    height:50px;
    top:10px;
    width:100px;
    border:3px solid red;
    display:block;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why youve done it the way you have.

Z-index can be used to put one div above another however there are better ways to do what you want.

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wVLa8/18/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="bottom">
<a href="#">LINK</a>
</div>
```

**css**

```
 .bottom {height:auto;width:100px;border:3px solid red;background:yellow; }
 .bottom a {display:block;margin:0 auto;background:yellow;padding:20px;text-align:center;}
```